# Accidentally backticking a non-binary function creates bizarre behaviour

Tags: haskell

Here's the offending code ([also on lpaste.net](http://lpaste.net/96826)):

```
module Data.Graph.Dijkstra
       ( dijkstra
       , dijkstraPath
       ) where

-- Graph library import
import Data.Graph.Inductive hiding (dijkstra)

-- Priority queue import
import qualified Data.PQueue.Prio.Min as PQ

-- Standard imports
import Data.List (find)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Data.Monoid

-- Internal routine implementing Dijkstra's shortest paths
-- algorithm. Deemed internal because it needs to be kickstarted with
-- a singleton node queue. Based on FGL's current implementation of
-- Dijkstra.
dijkstraInternal ::
  (Graph gr, Ord b, Monoid b) => gr a b -> PQ.MinPQueue b [Node] -> [[Node]]
dijkstraInternal g q
  | PQ.null q = []
  | otherwise =
    case match v g of
      (Just cxt,g') -> p:dijkstraInternal  g' (PQ.unions (q' : expand cxt minDist p))
      (Nothing, g') -> dijkstraInternal g' q'
  where ((minDist,p@(v:_)), q') = PQ.deleteFindMin q
        expand (_,_,_,s) dist pathToC =
          map (\(edgeCost,n) -> PQ.singleton (dist `mappend` edgeCost) (n:pathToC)) s

-- Given a graph and a start node, returns a list of lists of nodes
-- corresponding to the shortest paths from the start to all other
-- nodes, where the edge costs are accumulated according to the Monoid
-- instance of the edge label type and costs are compared by the edge
-- label's Ord instance.
dijkstra :: (Graph gr, Ord b, Monoid b) => gr a b -> Node -> [[Node]]
dijkstra g start = dijkstraInternal g (PQ.singleton `mempty` [start])  -- !!!

dijkstraPath :: (Graph gr, Ord b, Monoid b) => gr a b -> Node -> Node -> [LNode a]
dijkstraPath g start goal =
  let paths = dijkstra g start
      pathNodes  = find ((goal ==) . head) paths -- Can paths be empty?
  in
   case pathNodes of
     Nothing -> []
     Just ps -> reverse $ map (\n -> (n, fromJust $ lab g n)) ps
```

The weirdness is in line 39, marked with the `-- !!!` comment. This code compiles, but the runtime error is that no matter what, the `PQ.singleton` function returns an empty priority queue. I realized I had accidentally added backticks to `mempty`, so when I removed those the code compiled and worked as expected.

This however struck me as strange. How could the code have correctly compiled with backticks around `mempty`, which is not a binary function at all (`mempty :: a`)?

After some very generous help on #haskell, I found that it had something to do with the Monoid instance for functions:

```
instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)
```

I now have an extremely vague understanding of why this error successfully typechecked, but I still feel somehow morally wronged. Can someone explain exactly how this happened?

Additionally, I'd also like to direct attention to the priority queue's `singleton` function that I'm using: according to [the source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pqueue-1.2.1/docs/src/Data-PQueue-Prio-Internals.html#singleton), it doesn’t return an empty queue. However, at line 24, that same priority queue immediately gets evaluated as being empty. (I verified this with trace calls.)

Comment: What's the problem you're having with the monoid instance? You said #haskell explained it, so what's still unclear?

Comment: From their explanation I understand that this particular Monoid instance must be the root cause, but I still can't wrap my head around exactly how it works. Also, I believe that a public answer to this question would be really helpful to the Haskell community at large (and myself!) for understanding the Monoid instance of (->).

Comment: Not that you can apply that instance twice, meaning that `a -> b -> c` is an instance of `Monoid` if `c` is a `Monoid`, so it's a perfectly valid binary function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, in general, the code:

```
a `f` b
```

is just syntactic sugar for:

```
f a b
```

Therefore your code became:

```
mempty PQ.singleton [start]
```

So the type-checker inferred the type for that particular  mempty:

```
mempty :: (k -> a -> PQ.MinPQueue k a) -> [Node] -> PQ.MinPQueue b [Node]
```

You correctly found the right instance that is the problem.  Anything of type `a -> b` is a `Monoid`, provided that `b` is.  So let's bracket that type above:

```
mempty :: (k -> a -> PQ.MinPQueue k a) -> ([Node] -> PQ.MinPQueue b [Node])
```

So, that type can be a `Monoid` if `[Node] -> PQ.MinPQueue b [Node]` is a `Monoid`.  And by the same logic, `[Node] -> PQ.MinPQueue b [Node]` can be a `Monoid` if `PQ.MinPQueue b [Node]` is one.  Which it is.  So the type-checker is fine with this code.

Presumably the implementation of our troublesome instance is:

```
instance Monoid => Monoid (a -> b) where
  mempty = const mempty
```

So overall, you get an empty priority queue.  So really, I think it comes down to a question of whether it was wise for the designers to include this instance at all.  Its net effect is that any function returning a monoid can be a monoid, which should allow you to combine the results.  The more useful case here is mappend, which can append two `a -> b` functions by applying them both and using `mappend` to combine the results.  For example:

```
extremes = (return . minimum) `mappend` (return . maximum)
```

rather than:

```
extremes xs = [minimum xs, maximum xs]
```

Hmmm, maybe someone else can produce a sensible terser example.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I actually hadn't realized that PQ.MinPQueue b [Node] was a Monoid.

Comment: So do you think anything could have been done to prevent this kind of strangeness from occurring, or was this just a rare, unavoidable perfect storm of types perfectly re-aligning unexpectedly? You hinted at possibly pointing blame at the Monoid instance of (a -> b); would we really lose anything useful by removing that? Or maybe just hiding that instance behind a newtype?

Comment: A use of this `Monoid (a -> b)` instance is `sortBy (comparing foo \`mappend\` comparing bar)`.

Answer (score 5):

So backticks turn a binary function into an infix operator, making

```
x `op` y
```

equivalent to

```
op x y
```

So `op` needs to be of type `a -> b -> c` where `x :: a` and `y :: b`.

In your case, `op` was `mempty`, with the type `Monoid m => m`. But we know it to be of the form `a -> b -> c`, so substitute that and you get (this is no longer valid syntax) `Monoid (a -> b -> c) => a -> b -> c`, because we can substitute that `m` for anything as long as the constraint holds.

Now we know (due to the instance declaration) that any function of the form `s -> t`, where `t` is a Monoid, is a Monoid itself, and we also know that `a -> b -> c` is really `a -> (b -> c)`, i.e. a function taking one argument and returning another function. So if we substitute `a` for `s` and `(b -> c)` for `t`, the we fulfill the Monoid instance, if `t` is a Monoid. Of course, `t` is `(b -> c)`, so we can apply the same Monoid instance again (with `s = b` and `t = c`), so if `c` is a Monoid, we're good.

So what is `c`? The expression you had was

```
PQ.singleton `mempty` [start]
```

i.e.

```
mempty PQ.singleton [start]
```

The instance declaration for `Monoid (a -> b)` defines `mempty _ = mempty`, i.e. it's a function that ignores its argument and returns the empty element of the `b` Monoid. In other words, we can expand the call above to

```
mempty [start]
```

i.e. we ignore the argument and use mempty of the inner Monoid (which is `b -> c`). Then we repeat, ignoring the argument again:

```
mempty
```

So the expression you had is just equivalent to a single `mempty`, which has the type `Monoid c => c`, i.e. it can be any Monoid whatsoever.

In your case, the larger expression deduces `c` to be a `PQ.MinPQueue`. And `MinPQueue` is a Monoid instance with `mempty` being the empty queue.

This is how you end up with the result you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You've had a couple good answers here already, I thought I would just post this since it's a bit simpler and helped me as I was puzzling this out in ghci.

`mempty :: (a -> b) = mempty _ = mempty`  So it's essentially `const mempty`.

```
λ> :t mempty :: (a -> b)
<interactive>:1:1:
    No instance for (Monoid b) arising from a use of `mempty'
```

So `b` has to be a `Monoid` since we're asking for the `mempty` of that type, makes sense.

```
λ> :t mempty :: (a -> [b])
mempty :: (a -> [b]) :: a -> [b]
λ> :t mempty :: (a -> c -> [b])
mempty :: (a -> c -> [b]) :: a -> c -> [b]
```

We can recursively chain these.  Since `(->)` is right associative `(a -> b)` may represent `(a -> c -> d)` when `b == (c -> d)`.  So we can supply an arbitrary number of arguments and the `mempty` for functions will be recursively applied until it's consumed all arguments.

```
λ> import Data.Map
λ> (mempty :: (a -> c -> Map Int Int)) 4 5
fromList []
λ> (mempty :: (a -> c -> d -> Map Int Int)) 4 5 6
fromList []
```

So we see that applying the function `mempty` will throw away any arguments it's given and return the `mempty` for whatever type is expected at the position the expression is in.